# Creating macro parameters from integers

Tags: expl3

TeX Modes are still fuzzy to me. Here's a question to clarify the issue: If a function is passed an integer, say m, as parameter #1, how to create a macro parameter ##m from #1?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Naive approach to create macro parameters:

\cs_set:Npn \__foo_code:n #1{(## #1)} % Wanted: concac ## and #1<-int, (an integer) to yiel
\cs_set:Npn \__bar_code:n #1{[## #1]} 
\cs_set:Npn \__baz:nn #1 #2
{
    \__foo_code:n{1}
    \__bar_code:n{2}
}


\begin{document}

\__baz:nn{x}{y} % Wanted: (x)[y]
% Getting: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can do this, as shown below, but it's a rather unusual thing to do, what's the use case here?  It's worth noting that tex doesn't really have integers just tokens `12` is the two tokens 1 and 2, and `#1` are two tokens that get replaced by the 1st argument, and `##` are two tokens that get replaced by `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, just one letter changed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Naive approach to create macro parameters:

\cs_set:Npn \__foo_code:n #1{(## #1)} % Wanted: concac ## and #1<-int, (an integer) to yiel
\cs_set:Npn \__bar_code:n #1{[## #1]} 
\cs_set:Npx \__baz:nn #1 #2
{
    \__foo_code:n{1}
    \__bar_code:n{2}
}


\begin{document}

\__baz:nn{x}{y} % Wanted: (x)[y]
% Getting: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Y doesn't `\cs_set` accept other signatures (No, Nf)?